# Call to undefined function wpcf7_enqueue_styles()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

We have installed a new theme for Wordpress from Themeforest.

But, after login to **WP-admin** when we click on All Post or Post option to check the list of available posts/blogs, I,m getting this error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wpcf7_enqueue_styles() in /xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxx/functions/plugins-integration/contact7.php on line 32

As soon as I disable the contact form, everything starts working fine.

I tried disabling **wpcf7_enqueue_styles()** function, then it error changes to **wpcf7_enqueue_script()** and after updating Contact form 7 plugin but that too does not seems to work either.

Comment: Could you please code in contact7.php line 32

Comment: One option is to wrap your function calls in a check to see if that function exists: https://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/

Comment: @Dmitry can you explain ??

Comment: @MonkeyD.Luffy Show please code in contact7.php line 32

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to contact your **xxx** theme provider support or just read documentation to know which version of CF7 plugin compatible with your theme.

Comment: I tried downgrading and updating the version of WPCF7 also tried contacting the theme provider, but nothing worked for me.